# how to build an iphone apps in phonegap online or on windows? (without mac system)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

I developed android apps in phonegap and it is successfully work on all android versions now I want to run my app on iPhone which is ceated in phonegap. I know xcode IDE but its a need Mac System. I don't have mac system.  I have some questions...

Q.1) can I develop and create iphone apps on a cloud for **phonegap**(free and license)?

Q.2) can I create ipa online?

Q.3) can we run Mac in VM, but I dont want to use that(its slow,sluggish and painful to use).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop for cross platform that is, Android and iOS, you can try Mobione Studio, which doesn't require Mac, it runs only on Windows. 
It's a paid IDE and design studio, which has 15 days trial period.

Also, it's project structure is same as that of Phonegap, as it has Cordova base.

Comment: I think adode provide tools to develop cross platform on cloud. do you  know that? I have ready code now i want to create ipk?

Comment: Okay, no idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

Q1) Yes you can.

Q2) Yes, with Phonegap BUild you get an ipa.

Q3) I don't know about this.

Be aware - like the previous reply said - you'll need to use a service to upload to iTunes if you don't have a Mac.

If you have a Mac (of any kind) you can use that to upload the ipa you build with Phonegap Build.